# How to resize a YUVImage to JPG?

Tags: java, android, image-processing

I'm getting an `Image` from a decoder, in `YUV_420_888` format.

I've learnt here that I can convert it to NV21, to use like this:

```
Rect cropRect = myImage.getCropRect();
YuvImage yuvImage = new YuvImage(convertToNV21(myImage),
                                            ImageFormat.NV21,
                                            cropRect.width(),
                                            cropRect.height(),
                                            null);
yuvImage.compressToJpeg(cropRect, 100, jpegDataStream);
```

This way I have the correct JPG data in `jpegDataStream`.

`convertToNV21` function operates with image's planes, and do a lot of shifting, and heavily using `getRowStride` and `getPixelStride` (I can share it if you ask and think it's useful for better help).

My desire is to get a JPG with **lower** resolution, so I need to resize the image.

I know well how can I resize a JPG by first converting it to bitmap -> resize -> convert back to JPG, but it feels too much overhead.

Do I have an easier way somewhere maybe even before `compressToJpeg` to resize the YUVImage easily and efficiently?

Comment: I believe it will be easier to resample if you have a normal raster at least. You don't need to convert the YUV to RGB though, I don't think the resampling algorithms care about the color space. Perhaps you could resample each plane (as a grayscale raster) too.

Comment: Thanks, I'm kindof beginner in image (pre)processing, could you please add an answer with details about how can I resample it? If you need more info, please let me know and I'll add my current `convertToNV21` code. Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, I just have time for some ideas. I will have to leave it to someone else to implement a full solution/answer.